# Migrating from SQL Server to IBM Filent P8

Tags: sql-server, migration

I am Newbie to IBM Filenet P8. I was trying to migrate my sample SQL Server database to IBM Filenet the other day and was stuck right at the beginning. I was just wondering FROM WHERE I SHOULD BEGIN. I've tried searching online for resources but none of them walked me through.

Please help and on this from the basics on how to migrate a database from SQL Server to IBM Filenet P8.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/filecontmana/ if anyone was wondering